# Azure DevOps - Pipeline to pull code down to remote server

Tags: azure-devops

I am attempting to create a pipeline in our Azure DevOps org that will automatically 'pull' code down to a single remote server whenever a push request is sent to the master branch of my particular repo.  I am having a difficult time understanding the entire process and what I actually need to accomplish this relatively simple pipeline.

Currently, my remote server has a folder on the C: drive with various .ps1 files.  I would like to turn this into my repo and install the self-hosted agent on this same server so that way anytime I push something to the master branch on my **local** server it will automatically be pulled down to my **remote** server and the scheduled tasks I have running will pick be running the most up to date code.

I believe what I need to do first is install a self-hosted agent on my **remote** server.  I am not completely sure though if this agent is suppose to be a deployment agent or a build agent.. or both?  Since I am not technically building a project, but rather simply overwriting .ps1 files, I imagine it should only be given permissions for a deployment agent.

Something else I can't wrap my head around is how I specify the location of my repo on the remote server.  Can I define this dynamically or do I need to specify in my path the target path of that specific repo?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you could simplify your requirement to be: copy files from a source folder to a target folder on a remote machine over SSH using [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops), and then run related Git commands like the following.

```
cd repo_directory
git add .
git commit -m "upadte"
git push
```

Thus this remote repo is updated using [SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops).

In addition, you need to [deploy a self-hosted build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) because it can be used in build pipeline.

Finally, [configuring a schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) for this build pipeline.

Comment: What if I have multiple source folders? I.e. multiple users commiting to the same repo from different machines

Comment: I don't get your point, could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: I have a devops repo that is shared with my team. I may have a cloned copy on my local PC and my teammates may have a cloned version as well. Whenever an update is made and pushed by any one of us, I want the code to go to devops and then be pulled down to the c:/ drive of the server where that same repo has been closed down

Comment: In that case, you could use Azure Git repo. And create pipeline using this repo and set up CI trigger for it, so each push will trigger a new build to pull down to the c:/driver. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic for details.

Comment: Yea that is the plan, but still trying to gather the details. I just got admin perm to add a self hosted agent to one of the agent pools so I will give it a shot tomorrow. Trying to get the YAML down will be another story

Comment: If there is any update, please feel free to let me know. BTW, classic pipeline is easier configured than yaml pipeline in case of you are not familiar with yaml.